# How to put POCOs and Context in different namepsaces?

Tags: entity-framework

I know two ways how to put POCOs and context into differens assemblies but both variants implies that Custom Tool Namespace for Model.Context.tt and Model.tt are the same.

CodeStringGenreator class defined in Model.Context.tt uses heavily TypeMapper class but I cannot find any documentation about this class.
I suspect it to be the right place where to set namespace for POCOs.

I'd I appreciate any helpful advice besides "Leave context and POCOs in one namespace"

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Aren't entities somewhat coupled with the data model anyway?

Comment: @retailcoder Yes, there's no practical sense in it but quite often these tasks help to understand inner guts of technology.

Comment: If you have two separate .tt files, I don't see why you can't set the "Custom Tool Namespace" for each. Inside the .tt files, these are usually read by calling a function named `VsNamespaceSuggestion`.